# Simulate a webcam like the facebook 360 view using python

Tags: python, opencv, 360-degrees

I have been googled for a while but couldn't find any concrete solution in building a 360 webcam simulator. I am looking to build something like the facebook 360 viewer using python. A static image / short video will be used.

I have looked up opencv but didnt find anything close to it. Anyone can give me a direction on where to go?

Thanks!

Comment: BTW: [hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) - Panorama photo stitcher, [panotools.org](http://wiki.panotools.org/Main_Page) - you can find some tools and tutorials.

Comment: you build cubic like this https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/86/05/18/860518be9127c2477cefa3ffd8017b0e.jpg or http://thierry.loiseau.free.fr/panophoto_/cube-face-model-exemple.jpg